# UIScrollView scrollrecttovisible method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollview`(Horizontal) with a `UIview` as a subview, here i can able to drag the uiview inside the `scrollview`, the contentSize of `scrollview` is 2400. When i dragging that uiview it's not visible i.e, it's going inside the scrollview because my scrollview width is small, i need to scroll the `scrollview` to **make visible of UIView**. For this i have use

```
[myscroll scrollRectToVisible:myview.frame animated:YES];
```

but still its not working, please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your case,`[myscroll scrollRectToVisible:myview.frame animated:YES];` will not work because of *myview* is a sub-view of *myscroll*. `myview.frame` will return the CGRect which is only related to the *myscroll*.

My suggestion is , you can acheive the functionality through **UIpageControl + UIScrollView** . You can set UIPageControl as **Hidden**.

**SampleCode**

```
int page = sidePager.currentPage + 1;
CGRect frame = scroller.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;

if (0 != UpAndDownPager.currentPage) {

     frame.origin.y = frame.size.height * (UpAndDownPager.currentPage + 1 );
}

scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];       
sidePager.currentPage = sidePager.currentPage + 1;
```

**Note:**

**sidePager**: UIPageControl For Right-Left position

**UpAndDownPager**: UIPageControl For Top-Bottom position

Comment: is it possible without UIPageControl..?

Comment: yes. you have to get the exact touch point in scrollview related to your mainview.

Comment: myview.frame will not add the x position of scrolled area.It will return just the CGRect related its superview..

Comment: you may have good concepts & calculations to achieve this goal without pager control. Just hide  pager control :)

Answer (score -2):

```
scrollView.contentSize.width != 0 
&&
scrollView.contentSize.height != 0
```